# Even if we do not know of a single parametrization, can we prove that one exists, or does not exist? ($3$ as a sum of three cubes)

Tags: number-theory

There are parametrizations for $1$ and $2$.

One for $1$ is: $$(9b^4)^3+(3b-9b^4)^3+(1-9b^3)^3=1$$ and for $2$: $$(1+6c^3)^3+(1-6c^3)^3+(-6c^2)^3=2$$

But, it seems that there are no known parametrizations for $3$, if I understood correctly Wikipedia article.

If I were to try to construct them, I would try to find three polynomials $P(m)+1$ and $Q(m)+1$ and $R(m)+1$ so that we have $$(P(m)+1)^3+(Q(m)+1)^3+(R(m)+1)^3=3$$.

But this is obviously equivalent to: $$(P(m))^3+3(P(m))^2+3P(m)+(Q(m))^3+3(Q(m))^2+3Q(m)+(R(m))^3+3(R(m))^2+3R(m)=0$$

But what can now be done?

From $3|(P(m))^3+(Q(m))^3+(R(m))^3$ it seems that we should have $3|P(m)$ and $3|Q(m)$ and $3|R(m)$.

Now I was thinking on expanding $(P(m)+Q(m)+R(m))^3$ and then subtracting it from  $(P(m))^3+3(P(m))^2+3P(m)+(Q(m))^3+3(Q(m))^2+3Q(m)+(R(m))^3+3(R(m))^2+3R(m)$

but I am stuck, literally, because I do not know would I obtain something of relevance.

What can we do here?

Are there any heuristics that suggest that such $P,Q,R$ do not exist?

I also suppose that constant terms of $P$ and $Q$ and $R$ are equal to zero.

Comment: You are stuck on an open problem. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes#cite_note-arb-10) writes that there are no solutions for $3$ other than some trivial solutons. In addition, $42$  has no known representation.

Comment: @TobyMak This is different, I am not trying to find solutions for $3$, but to prove that there is no polynomial parametrization.

Comment: For more information see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58188/are-nontrivial-integer-solutions-known-for-x3y3z3-3?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126186/sum-of-three-cubes-and-parametric-solutions/126713#126713) and further ones.